# MSE for MLE of geometric distribution

Tags: probability, statistics

This is based on a friend's homework problem in a past semester.

Suppose I have $n$ iid geometric random variables $X_i$ with $Pr(X_i=k)=p(1-p)^{k-1}$ for some $p$. It is easy to calculate the MLE as $\frac{n}{\sum{X_i}}$. But how would I calculate the mean square error of the maximum likelihood estimate? It seems I would need to compute $E\left[\frac{1}{\sum{X_i}}\right]$ in the process and the computation doesn't seem easy.

Answer (score 2):

To compute the exact MSE of $1/\bar{X}_n$ you will have to use the distribution of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$  which follows the negative Binomial distribution, i.e., $ NB(n,p) $. Then, for the expectation you have to compute the following series 
$$
E(n/\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)=nE(1/\sum_{i=1}^n X_i) = n\sum_{m=n}^{\infty}\frac{1}{y} \binom{m-1}{n-1}p^n(1-p)^{m-n}. 
$$
And the same principle for the second moment. I'm not sure that it has simple analytical solutions. I  would rather use approximated solutions (hoping that the $n$ will be large enough). I.e., $\bar{X}_n$ is approximately normal and then for its inverse you can use the delta method to approximate its parameters and particularly its variance.

Comment: I am not sure if I need to calculate $E\left[\frac{1}{\sum{X_i}}\right]$. There may be a way to side step it.

Comment: If you are interested in the exact solution, there is no way to side step such calculations.